# Save images like facebook newsfeed while having no internet ANDROID

Tags: android

How does facebook newsfeed do it? How am I still able to see newsfeed even if I have no internet connection? In Android phone

Comment: Enable cache at the time of image loading which will save images in cache memory. Btw which library you are using to load image. I mean like glide, fresco, picassa or UIL etc.